# primefaces3.0 datatable selection and value property

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have upgraded my project from  Primefaces 2.2 to 3.0
I am facing problems in Datatable. I have a Datatable whose values i am populating through a list and selected rows are kept in array

```
    <p:dataTable id="datavalues" value="#{bean.list}" 
                        var="o" paginator="true" rows="10" 
                        selection="#{bean.selected1}"           
                           rowKey="#{o.property1}"  >
```

now i want the selected rows to be used in another Datatable and on that Datatable i have used values as "#{bean.selected1}" and selection as #{bean.selected2} as i also need the selected values from this Table.

```
<p:dataTable id="table4" var="o" value="#{bean.selected1}"
                rows="10"           
                selection="#{bean.selected2}"           
                     rowKey="#{o.property2}"        
                >
```

The Exception I got is :

```
[Lcom.packagedirectory.beans.beanHelper; cannot be cast to java.util.Collection
```

list, selected1, selected2 are all properties of beanHelper Class.
This code was perfectly working on 2.2  Has it something to do with That value is also an array and selection is also an array.

Answer (score 0):

In Primefaces 2.2 the selection would have updated its bean value automatically, however this was probably not desirable for every situation, so in 3.0 they changed it so that for an ajax postback to occur you need to place a `<p:ajax>` tag with a `rowSelect` event within the dataTable.

```
<p:dataTable id="table1" ... >
  <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="formid:table1 formid:table2" oncomplete="dlg.show()" />
  ...
</p:dataTable>

<p:dataTable id="table2" ... >
  ...
</p:dataTable>
```

Selections of the first dataTable should trigger the server postback and partial page update of your second dataTable.

Comment: thanks for ur reply. my datatables are in different .xhtml pages. How to update ids for different pages

Comment: I didn't see the edit with the exception, so this may just be a code problem in your beanHelper class.  Without seeing your code I have no way of telling.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to add `selectionMode="multiple"` in your 1st `<p:dataTable>` and `selectionMode="single"` in your 2nd `<p:dataTable>`.

Comment: i have to select multiple items from second datatable also.

Comment: @curious then both `selected1` and `selected2` must be `List`